# javascript sorting a map based on it's attribute and return map

Tags: javascript, canjs

I am trying to sort a map which is inside a filter and return the map

```
  var sort = this.attr('component').attr('sort');
  if (sort == 'Price Descending')
  {
     return this.attr('%root.products').filter(function(product) {
            // How can I sort 'product' here before returning? 
            return (product.attr(product.attr('active') !== 'f';
     });
  }
```

As mentioned above how can I sort the product callback variable before returning and comparing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a map basically, and it's being filtered to an array

Comment: Yes, it's a map, which returns a promise which has been resolved. `prodcut.attr('price')` consists the price, and I need to sort it descendingly before returning it

Comment: I don't see how `attr()` is returning anything other than a string.  If `this` is a jQuery object, `attr()` returns a string.  http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: `this` is a map, the viewModel, recieved by `var self = this` inside the attribute scope. https://canjs.com/ lord

Comment: So this has nothing to do with jQuery, as noted in the OP title and the tag

Comment: It's jQuery all around, `.filter()` is jquery , `.attr()` is jquery, I have to use jquery to sort the price

Comment: No, no it's not.  If you are using the native javascript methods, it is **not** jQuery.

Comment: I just posted a solution with javascript, I would like to know if it is a good fit for @Cowgirl

Comment: Cowgirl I think you need to give us more context for assistance.  The answer that @juangarcia gave should work theoretically, but we have no ideas about the data you have or the scope of your function calls. As is your code is atypical, without a proper description you're probably not going to get a very well-defined answer.

Comment: @Cowgirl is using CanJS that actually works with a Map, my mistake I saw the code so much javascript, once you see the library CanJS things should be done a different way as the prototype of Map is not the same as in Array, there was a chance to use List of CanJS and use a comparator, but is deprecated... I don't have a solution in hands at least for the next hour...